# Xpath php: get attribute value start with

Tags: php, xpath

I would like to extract in an html page all the attribute names that start with **ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_** and check if the input tag is checked. For example I have this piece of html code:

```
                 <tr>
                    <td operazione="ritira"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRitira_852428" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_852428" /><label for="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRitira_852428">Ritira</label></td>
                    </tr>                   
                <tr>
                    <td operazione="ritira"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRitira_852429" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_852429" /><label for="ctl00_ctl00_mainContent_bodyContent_chkRitira_852429"> Ritira</label></td>
                   </tr>
```

I want to check if every input check that starts with  **ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_** is checked and the name of the attribute, then:

```
ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_852428
ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_852429
```

I tried with:

```
 $xpR=new DOMXPath( $dom_richieste_r );
 $colR = $xpR->query( '//input[@name="ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_"]' );
```

But this gives me back the content of the node.

Answer (score 1):

`//input[contains(@name,'ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_')]`

Answer (score 1):

There is a [`starts-with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) that you can implement as below

```
//input[starts-with(@id, "ctl00$ctl00$mainContent$bodyContent$chkRitira_")]/@name
```